# Inequality between two recurrence relations

Tags: recurrence-relations

Let's define two recurrence relations with $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $x \in \left]0 ;1\right[$ as:

$$
\begin{align}
a_0 &= 1 \\
a_n &= -x \left( a_{n-1} + n \right)
\end{align}
$$

and

$$
\begin{align}
b_0 &= 1 \\
b_n &= -f(x) \left( b_{n-1} + n \right)
\end{align}
$$

where $f(x) > x$ if $n$ is odd and $f(x) < x$ if $n$ is even.

**Question:** How to prove that $a_n > b_n$ if $n$ is odd and $a_n < b_n$ if n is even for all $n \ge 1$?

Comment: Is it true for $n=0,n=1$?

Comment: Your question is not right. The statement you want to prove doesn't follow for n=0 and n=1!

Comment: You are right. I edited the question. The inequality should be the opposite.